# Firebase in NodeJS with HTTP Proxy

Tags: firebase

I'm having some issues getting Node to connect to Firebase through a proxy.

The application works fine when not running via the proxy (on a dev machine), or if I am running in the browser behind a proxy. The problem occurs when it is deployed on a server that can't bypass the proxy.

I can't find any documentation on how Firebase picks up proxy settings, or how I can tell Firebase about the proxy. Is it possible to run Firebase (in Node) from behind a proxy? How should the proxy settings be configured?

Answer (score 8):

I am having same problem, and stumbled opon this thread.

@Kato: thanks for the hint!  For dev/test purpose, I hijacked faye-websocket and am able to connect via a proxy.

ie, in faye\websocket\client.js, I hardcoded (I know it is bad, but it should be fine for dev purposes) the below proxy config,

```
var Client = function(_url, protocols, options) {
  options = options || {};

  options.proxy = {
    origin:  'http://localhost:8888',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'node'},
  }  ....
```

It is connecting fine now :)

Comment: didn't work here. what is the module you are editing?

Comment: Why using port 8888?

Answer (score 4):

Alas, it doesn't look like there's any global way to tell node to use a proxy for its outgoing connections. It's a bit odd to have a server process behind a proxy. Usually, one would configure the server's Firewall to allow these socket connections, rather than trying to route them through a proxy.

If you're desperate, you can probably hijack faye-websocket's WebSocket implementation and add in the proxy info, similar to [this approach](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/09/05/semi-global-proxy-setting-for-node.js.aspx), but targeting faye-websocket instead of the http module.

Answer (score 2):

> var Client = function(_url, protocols, options) {
>
> options = options || {};
>
> options.proxy = {
>
> origin:  'http://localhost:8888',
>
> headers: {'User-Agent': 'node'},
>
> }  ....

my local proxy is "http://127.0.0.1:8118"

when I changed proxy uri , it works to me . thaks @jho

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155) in `firebase-tools`, and it is [fixed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155#issuecomment-414007955) in 4.1.2.

Now you can set proxy in your environment variables:

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1234
```

And firebase will respect it.

Comment: please explain how to do this.