# How to setup EC2 Security Group to allow working with Firebase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firebase

I am preparing a system of EC2 workers on AWS that use Firebase as a queue of tasks they should work on.

My app in node.js that reads the queue and works on tasks is done and working and I would like to properly setup a firewall (EC2 Security Group) that allows my machines to connect only to my Firebase.

Each rule of that Security Group contains:

- protocol
- port range
- and destination (IP address with mask, so it supports whole subnets)

My question is - how can I setup this rule for Firebase? I suppose that IP address of my Firebase is dynamic (it resolves to different IPs from different instances). Is there a list of possible addresses or how would you address this issue? Can some kind of proxy be a solution that would not slow down my Firebase drastically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since using node to interact with Firebase is *outbound* traffic, the default security group should work fine (you don't need to allow any inbound traffic).

If you want to lock it down further for whatever reason, it's a bit tricky.  As you noticed, there are a bunch of IP addresses serving Firebase.  You could get a list of them all with "dig -t A firebaseio.com" and add all of them to your firebase rules.  That would work for today, but there could be new servers added next week and you'd be broken.  To try to be a bit more general, you could perhaps allow all of 75.126.*.*, but that is probably overly permissive and could still break if new Firebase servers were added in a different data center or something.

FWIW, I wouldn't worry about it.  Blocking inbound traffic is generally much more important than outbound (since to generate outbound traffic you have to have already managed to somehow run software on the box)

Comment: I'd really like to block all traffic from the instances, because they are running on Windows Server and I find blocking everything outbound simpler that going in settings and deactivate all the Windows services that might run and prevent my app from working (like the automatic updates and so)

What do you think about making a proxy for my Firebase? Do you have any experience with that or is it even possible with this kind of realtime API?

Comment: Somebody else just asked about proxy support, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098328/firebase-in-nodejs-with-http-proxy/27113658#27113658 It should work (as long as the proxy supports websocket traffic).

If it's useful, all Firebase traffic will be on port 443 (HTTPS), so you could limit to that...