# Firebase login failed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm having troubles trying to migrate to new firebase console.
I'm doing exactly what is on this link: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#import_your_project_to_the_firebase_console_numbered

And this is what happened in the step 2:
***Firebase login failed
The Firebase CLI login request was rejected or an error occurred. Please run firebase login again or contact support if you continue to have difficulty logging in.***

Any ideas? Thanks since now.

Comment: You remove a similar domain before?

Comment: I did not added a domain and removed neither.

Comment: Check network, like proxy and firewall..

Comment: I try all kind of methods. But in my case just get fixed by restarting my PC. Yeah, weird and magic :(

Answer (score 59):

You should try the following:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

Comment: how did you find that out? a link to the docs would be really helpful

Comment: @Pete `firebase login --help`

Comment: I have similar problem and local host option didn't help :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028795/failed-to-authenticate-have-you-run-firebase-login

Answer (score 7):

A possible reason may be that you are using a proxy.

There is a issue on firebase: [Unable to deploy behind a proxy](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155)

If you are using proxy, you can refer to this question to: [Firebase in NodeJS with HTTP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098328/firebase-in-nodejs-with-http-proxy/28155536#28155536).

Comment: In my case I forgot to disable a traffic saver (TripMode) :)

Answer (score 7):

This will work most certainly!!!

Please try this command

```
set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"
```

and then re-run,

```
firebase login
```

Comment: use 'export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0' on mac or linux

Comment: Here is what worked for me since I am behind the firewall. I was trying to execute it from within WebStorm IDE terminal and even after setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0, I was getting the error.

Then, I did it from command prompt and then login. It worked. 

So, I would suggest that we do it from command prompt and not from within IDE if we are working with one of the IDEs which comes with the terminal

Answer (score 4):

> The Firebase CLI does not currently work behind a proxy.

We're aware of the issue but don't have a timeline for a fix. You can follow along with the tracked issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer but further details that don't get formatted correctly in the Comments

I have the same issue at an initial login

The steps I do are (from a cygwin terminal on Windows 10 Professional)

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

After this I get the message "

```
Visit the URL on any device....
Paste authentication code here:
```

Then, on my browser, I see Google asking if I give Firebase CLI access rights. I say yes and then I get an authorization code displayed on the browser.
I copy this code into the cygwin console and then......

```
Error: Authentication Error.
```

Answer (score 2):

Note firebase CLI uses HTTP_PROXY variable if it is set in your environment. (you can run **echo $HTTP_PROXY** to verify) So make sure you are *EITHER* in a network with access to your proxy (e.g. corporate network) *OR* that you **unset HTTP_PROXY** in the terminal that you use for firebase. Otherwise you will get this misleading error that says “Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid.”

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was coming due to network proxy before identification I tried all available solutions on internet.

This issue was there due to network proxy, due to proxy it could not get correct SSL. I requested my network team to direct my connection without proxy.

Hence, problem got solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can logout with **firebase logout** and login in with **firebase login**. It solves the problem with ease.

Answer (score 1):

On CLI following worked for me:

Try out For Windows :

- Search for PowerShell
- run as PowerShell administrator
- npm install -g firebase-tools
- firebase login
- firebase deploy

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are at workplace or behind a proxy. This a know error. You can follow the status of this issue here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might run across this issue and think to themselves, "But, I'm not *behind* a proxy...": I generally run [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch). (Note, I don't work for LS, just use the product. This isn't intended as an ad.) After a few minutes of consideration, I realized that it is, in essence, a proxy. I switched it off (by clicking the "Stop Network Filter" option), and presto, I was able to login. Then I switched Little Snitch back on.

**[Update]**

I was trying to test Cloud Functions locally using `firebase serve --only functions`. Once I turned Little Snitch back on, I started getting:

```
Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth
```

So apparently, you can't serve functions locally from behind a proxy, either. Turning LS filtering back off fixed the issue. There's probably a whitelisting option I could use, but I haven't explored that yet. I'm just trying to get back to work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is forced to use a VPN provider to connect, like Astrill for example, you cant use OpenWeb protocol.
Use StealthVPN. That solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add and enable Google provider in Authentication tab of your App before CLI for existing remote project created.

On CLI following worked for me :

- npm install -g firebase-tools
- firebase login
- firebase init

On Firebase login you get Web interface login to Google account on web browser, then you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your email like this :

`firebase login exmple@email.com`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the suggestions above. None of them were successful.

The only thing that worked for me was rebooting my machine (restarting the terminal was not sufficient). Logging in worked flawlessly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node and npm versions and try to update them once and try again firebase login It will work if It not solved by above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when installing `firebase-cli` using Homebrew on Mac.

First I searched for the certificate file in homebrew using terminal:

```
find / -name "cacert.pem"
```

This did print out a ton of stuff, but among the first results was a path to the correct file, you need a file inside the `ca-certificates` folder:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/2023-01-10/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem
```

Note: There is probably a better way to find the correct path, I just used this one.

Then I just ran this in terminal:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="/your/path/to/ca-certificates/cacert.pem"
```

After that `firestore login` is working properly. No need to switch of TLS.

To keep that working even after logout/restart the `export` command should be added into `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Firebase tools through the bash script and then got the exact error, which drove me crazy since all the above solutions do not work. I then tried to remove Firebase tool by

```
 curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash
```

and use the npm way to install. Surprisingly, I can login successfully to the Firebase