# Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am following instructions for [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). I have successfuly login from my console, however when I am trying to deploy functions, terminal gives an error:
[image]

*oleg@oleg-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/Desktop/Oleg/projects/firebase-functions$ firebase login*

*Already logged in as [my user email]*

*oleg@oleg-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/Desktop/Oleg/projects/firebase-functions$ sudo firebase deploy --only functions*

*Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?
(node:11224) MetadataLookupWarning: received unexpected error = Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 403 code = 403
Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help*

So the error is kind of controversial. Firstly, Firebase says that I am already successfully logged in. Right next, Firebase says that I am not logged in...
I suspect there should be some setting for user name or something like that in kind of local firebase.json file or other files, but I didn't find it.. Or should I change something in the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by removing sudo from the command.
Thanks for the response to the [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3509) community