# Google Cloud Function Deployment with firebase deploy: does nothing

Tags: function, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, freeze

While trying to deploy the sample [Google Actions Transactions API](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs) to Google Cloud Functions using firebase as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs), I encountered a problem where the `firebase deploy --only functions` just hanged doing nothing (did not print any error on firebase CLI). the firebase debug logs also did not give a clue of the issue.

Please help.

Thanks!

-Kunal

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaroud for this problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098328/firebase-in-nodejs-with-http-proxy/28155536#28155536). I am trying to deploy the Google Cloud Function using Firebase from behind a **corporate proxy**. It appears that Firebase does not read proxy settings from the environment variables. This is an [open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155).

**Workaround:**

Go to (on Windows)

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\client.js

And update code to use **your** proxy server:port-

```
`var Client = function(_url, protocols, options) {
 options = options || {};
 options.proxy = {
    origin:  '**YOUR_PROXY_SERVER:PORT**',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'node'},
  }`
```

This work around can be used in DEV mode until Firebase provides permanent fix.

Enjoy!